# How to style transposed MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm trying to format the following transposed multiindex dataframe:

```
        0   1   2   3
B   sum 22  22  0   0
    d   0   0   -22 -22
    d%  0   0   -1  -1
C   sum 30  15  30  60
    d   0   15  0   30
    d%  0   -0.5    1
```

I'd like to apply a `style.bar` and a `style.format("{:.2%}"` on rows with a second level index ending in `%`, but can't for the life of me figure out how to `subset` on rows in a MultiIndex dataframe.

I've tried playing with IndexSlice, and many other approches to no avail. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some playing around, passing tuples to `subset` works:

```
rows = [idx for idx in df.index if idx[1][-1]=='%']
df.style.format("{:.2%}",subset=(rows,pd.IndexSlice[:]))
# equivalently
# df.style.format("{:.2%}",subset=(rows,df.columns))
```

Output:

```
                   0        1              2    3
B   sum            0        1              2    3
     d%      400.00%     500.00%     600.00%    700.00%
C   sum            8           9          10    11
     d%     1200.00%    1300.00%    1400.00%    1500.00%
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is it just me, or this _should_ be way easier? :)